# Setting CPU Frequency on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-speed

I've setup an EC2 Instance on AWS Amazon, and I'm trying to change the CPU speed of the cores by following these steps:
https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/comment/1716807/how-to-change-frequency-on-linux-pub.txt

However, the folder cpu0/cpufreq does not exist.
What should I do?

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to control the CPU speed on a machine that is potentially sharing a CPU across multiple virtual machines? As you are in a VM why would you expect to be able to control the CPU of the host at all?

Comment: The only way to increase the CPU frequency is to pay Amazon for that frequency.  The documentation you linked to only applies to physical hardware and cannot be done within a EC2 instance

Comment: @Mokubai EC2 instances do not share CPU cores.  Cores and memory are dedicated to each VM.

Comment: Why are you trying to control CPU frequency? What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: While all the answers saying CPUs are not adjustable, this doc seems to tell something different? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't do anything. You don't have control of the physical CPU parameters because you are in a virtual machine.

From https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types

> Each vCPU is a thread of either an Intel Xeon core or an AMD EPYC core, except for T2 and m3.medium.

`vCPU` tells you that you are running a virtualized CPU rather than having all the hardware and control you expect of a "real" CPU.

If you want control of the CPU then chances are you need a dedicated server, not a VM instance.

Comment: Thank you! So something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/dedicated-instances/ ?

Comment: or this: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts ?

Comment: @TeresaSalazar No, not either of those. Those are still cases where your tasks are assigned virtual CPUs. It's just that the only virtual CPUs assigned to that physical CPU are yours. These are all solutions where Amazon manages the CPU performance for you.

Comment: Oh ok thank you @DavidSchwartz. What do you recommend using then?

Comment: @TeresaSalazar I don't know what you're trying to do, but the short answer is to buy exactly what you want rather than buying something else and trying to make it what you want.

Comment: @TeresaSalazar more like https://www.google.com/search?q=dedicated+server&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-m a dedicated server is a server that is 100% dedicated to you rather than being a shared "cloud" resource. If you want control of the CPU then you want to rent a *physical* server rather than just CPU time and memory. Generally dedicated servers will be more expensive. If you are paying by the hour (or even minute) then you are not going to get a "real" computer, you are getting a virtual machine which you don't have control over.

Answer (score 0):

You can control C-state and P-state configuration by modifying the kernel parameters passed to it from grub. Documentation explains how it works exactly at  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html

You can also specify CPU options when creating EC2 instances to control the use of Threads & Cores. As per the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html